# jQuery selects certain html contents

Tags: jquery

I am using this `.children()` selector to choose two types of contents between two `<div>s`.

1. table with class starting with "out_"
2. charts with id equal "chart1"

As a result I am using the following jQuery statement.

```
var jq_html = $("div.articles_output").children("table[class*=out_]:not(div#chart1,table:hidden)").clone().html();
```

HTML

```
<div class="articles_output">
        <h2 class="model_header">IEC Output</h2>
    <form>
        <table align="center">
            <!--end 04uberoutput_start-->
            <table width="600" border="1" class="out_1">
                <tr>
                    <th width="300" scope="col">User Inputs</th>
                    <th width="300" scope="col">Values</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>LC50 or LD50</td>
                    <td>33.00</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <table width="600" border="1" class="out_2">
                <tr>
                    <th width="300" scope="col">IEC Outputs</th>
                    <th width="300" scope="col">Values</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Z Score</td>
                    <td>5.95</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="600" border="1" class="out_2" style="display:none">
                <tr>
                    <th width="300" scope="col">IEC Outputs</th>
                    <th width="300" scope="col">Values</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Z Score</td>
                    <td>5.95</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </table>
        <div id="chart1" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:650px; height:400px;"></div>
        <div id="chart1" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:650px; height:400px;"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have realized something wrong with my `.children` argument. So can anyone give me some sugeestings? Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/wVnwg/).

### update

I think I found where caused the problem. But do not know how to solve it. If I removed the `form` tags. Then my jQuery statement will work. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/wVnwg/51/)

Comment: Try using `find` instead of `children`

Comment: Tried. It only gets me the first table.

Comment: your selector is correct, you just can't use `html()` to select the html of two elements at one time. 

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewP/SwdYc/) using loops to access the html of your two tables.

Comment: I think the clone method enables to select multiple html contents, and it was working before. But I just found it stopped working today...

Comment: `.find` vs `.children`, from the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/): "The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well." – if the tables you tried to select wouldn't have been nested in the `<form>`-tag, you would indeed be able to select them via `.children()`.

Comment: @tao.hong While I prefer the solution provided in the second comment by Drew, your updated jsfiddle seems to produce the same result, doesn't it? Also, your question states that you want to select "charts with id equal 'chart1' while your jQuery-selector clearly states `:not(div#chart1)`, which is a little confusing.

Comment: I appreciate Drew's solution. But as a learner. Why including the `form` tag breaks my jQuery statement?

Comment: Tao, as stated in my first comment: `.children()` will only select elements which are _direct_ children of the element you initially selected (`div.articles_output`). In your markup, these direct children are `h2` and `form`. `children()` simply "doesn't see" the `table`-elements you want to select, because they are children of the `form`-tag, which makes them grandchildren of `div.articles_output`.